# Gridview does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

this error

> "'gv' does not exist in the current context"

is shown when i try to load a gridview.
this is the first time that i see that error.
i work a lot to solve this error and dont succeed.
what i need to do to sove this error and load the grid view.
thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class usageDisp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionstring = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=globaldotdb; user ID=root; Password=peleg1708";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //check
           BindData();

        }
    }
    private void BindData()
    {         
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT  tblusage.codeUsage,tblcustom.Customer, tblvendor.Vendor, tblusage.dateStart, tblusage.dateEnd, tblregion.Region, tblservice.Service, tblservice.unit, tblusage.isSecure,tblusage.Usage FROM     ((((tblvendor INNER JOIN tblusage ON tblvendor.codeVendor = tblusage.codeVendor) INNER JOIN  tblservice ON tblusage.codeService = tblservice.codeService) INNER JOIN  tblregion ON tblusage.codeRegion = tblregion.codeRegion) INNER JOIN  tblcustom ON tblusage.codeCust = tblcustom.codeCust)"), cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();



            }
        }
    }
 }
}


<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usageDisp.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="usageDisp" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="codeUsage">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="codeusage" Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTCust" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeVendor") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateStart">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateEnd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="service">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTSe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="region">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTRe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="isSecure">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTIS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTunit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="usage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTusage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your ASPX code, this is not enough information.

Comment: Try to rename your grid to something else and then again to `gv`. Or clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: Are you able to access anything on your aspx in the code behind?  Without seeing the aspx page, my guess is that the aspx page is has a problem in the CodeFile or Inherits attributes.

Comment: i added the aspx code.
@TestWell

Comment: i able to access.
i meant that i dont know how to paste the html code but i pasted it already.
@tdbeckett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set value of Inherits to name of your class:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usageDisp.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.usageDisp" %>
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx#Inherits):

> **Inherits** - Defines a code-behind class for the page to inherit. This can
>   be any class derived from the Page class. This attribute is used with
>   the CodeFile attribute, which contains the path to the source file for
>   the code-behind class. The Inherits attribute is case-sensitive when
>   using C# as the page language, and case-insensitive when using Visual
>   Basic as the page language.