# ASP.NET display data from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm trying to display items from a list on my webpage, and I'm getting some errors. Here's my code for the display:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repZips" runat="server">  
    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>- <%# Container.DataItem  %>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tr></table>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CodeBehind:

```
    List<int> zips = (List<int>)ListZips.getZips();
    repZips.DataSource = zips;
    repZips.DataBind();
```

There are several errors in this codebehind:

> -the name repZips.DataSource does not exist in the current context
>
> -the name DataSource does not exist in the current context
>
> -the name zips does not exist in the current context
>
> -the name repZips.DataBind does not exist in the current context
>   -the name DataBind does not exist in the current context

Do I need to import something or define things differently so that I can use this sort of format? I'm just trying to display everything in the list "zips" on my page.

Comment: you have a spelling mistake in `<asp:Reapeater`

Comment: Thanks; fixed it. That wasn't the problem, though.

Comment: you probably have other compiler errors, like missing a curly brace or something.  This is why it doesn't recognize the repZips object

Comment: @techspider Maybe he/she really wants eveything in one row..

Comment: @techspider: thanks for the suggestion; it still can't recognize the objects.

Comment: @easymoney202: there isn't anything else in that class except the namespace and class definition--so I'm not missing anything as far as I can tell

Comment: may be OP needs to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482080/gridview-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, sorry to bother everyone--thanks for the comments.

If anyone else is having a problem like this, make sure that the stuff I have listed in the code behind is inside the method Page_Load. Worked fine then.